# Error when removing a class in the mobile version.Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList');

Tags: javascript

I have some div elements that have a '.swiper-slide' class. I need this class to be removed on the mobile version of the screen. However, I am getting the error. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')Please tell me how to fix it
My js:

```
function overlay() {
        let swiperSlide = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide');
        if (window.innerWidth < 991) {
            swiperSlide.forEach((swip, index) => {
                swip[index].classList.remove('swiper-slide');
            });
        } else {
           swiperSlide.forEach((swip, index) => {
                swip[index].classList.add('swiper-slide');
            });

        }
    };
    overlay();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
swip[index].classList.remove('swiper-slide');
```

In the callback to `forEach`, the first argument (in this case `swip`) isn't a *copy* of the array over which you're iterating.  It's the *individual element* for any given iteration over the list.  So you'd access it directly:

```
swip.classList.remove('swiper-slide');
```

If you wanted to use the `index` (the second argument to the callback) then you'd use that on the *array*, not the *element*:

```
swiperSlide[index].classList.remove('swiper-slide');
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it helped me